# Changing UIImageView Image from a 'UIImagePickerController' in another ViewController crashes with 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil'

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 `UIViewController`s:

ViewController 'A' named 'RERUN_SETUP' with an `UIImageView` and ViewController 'B' named 'SelectPhotos' with an `imagePickerController`.

There is an empty transparent `UIButton` over the `UIImageView` in ViewController 'A', which pops up ViewController 'B' and allows the user to select adding a picture from Camera or from Photos. ViewController 'A' is declared in ViewController 'B', but when I try to change the `UIImageView` on ViewController 'A' from ViewController 'B', the app crashes with an error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Below is my code, any help will be greatly appreciated :)

ViewController 'A'

```
class RERUN_SETUP: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate  {
 //USER PICTURE
    @IBOutlet weak var RERUNpictureIn: UIImageView?

//TRANSPARENT BUTTON OVER THE IMAGE VIEW
@IBAction func imageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectPhotos")


    popoverContent!.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverContent?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal
    var popover = popoverContent!.popoverPresentationController

    if let popover = popoverContent!.popoverPresentationController {

        let viewForSource = sender
        popover.sourceView = self.view
        popoverContent!.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(100,80)
        popover.delegate = self
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = .Any


    }

    self.presentViewController(popoverContent!, animated: true, completion: nil)





}
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {


    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None


}
```

ViewController 'B'

```
import UIKit

class SelectPhotos: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
var savedImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("image")
var imageToSave = UIImage()
var otherController:RERUN_SETUP = RERUN_SETUP()

@IBAction func camera(sender: UIButton) {

    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func photos(sender: AnyObject) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    self.imageToSave = image

    otherController.RERUNpictureIn!.image = image
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In View Controller B in your image picker delegate method save your image to nsuserdefault and in your viewconroller A get that image from nsuserdefault. and set the image.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageData!, forKey: "image")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

and in your View Controller where you want to set the image

```
let imageData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("image") as! NSData
imgView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting nil for RERUNpictureIn `ImageView`, is that it has not initalized yet for that empty object you have declare named `otherController` inside your `SelectPhotos` controller, Also that object will not helpful because the object you have create it not belongs to the object that is currently running with your application.

To send image to previous one you can use `delegate/protocol` for that.

First declare one protocol like this and implement with your `RERUN_SETUP` Controller

```
protocol ImageDelegate {
    func getImage(image: UIImage)
}
```

Now implement it inside your

```
class RERUN_SETUP: UITableViewController, ImageDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate  {

    //Your Code

    //Implement method of ImageDelegate
    func getImage(image: UIImage) {
         self.RERUNpictureIn.image = image
    }
}
```

Now add one object of `ImageDelegate` inside your `SelectPhotos` controller

```
import UIKit

class SelectPhotos: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var savedImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("image")
    var imageToSave = UIImage()
    var delegate: ImageDelegate?

    @IBAction func camera(sender: UIButton) {

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    @IBAction func photos(sender: AnyObject) {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        self.imageToSave = image
        self.delegate.getImage(self.imageToSave)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

**Note:** Now inside `RERUN_SETUP` controller where you are creating object of `SelectPhotos` for presenting the view, just add one line before presenting the object.

```
objectOfSelectPhotosThatYouHvaeCreated.delegate = self
```

Comment: sorry about the late reply ... actually now it doesn't crash, but the imageView doesn't change it's picture.

Comment: this line in SelectPhotos gives me an error "Value of type SelectPhotos' has no member 'getImage'

self.getImage(self.imageToSave)

Comment: I forgot to add delegate, check my edit, it is like this `self.delegate.getImage(self.imageToSave)`

Comment: now crashes with 'unexpectedly found nil ...' pointing to  self.delegate!.getImage(self.imageToSave)
btw I didn't understand this - objectOfSelectPhotosThatYouHvaeCreated.delegate = self - which object should I put there?

Comment: Please add the code that you have written to present `SelectPhotos` inside `RERUN_SETUP` controller.

Comment: Please find the code, I edited it. Btw I have 2 working buttons in RERUN_SETUP ViewController and another solution for me would be to access them from SelectPhotos. Please let me know if I have to put the whole RERUN_SETUP code. I didn't publish it because it's large and there are other parts not related to the question...

Comment: Add this line `popoverContent.delegate = self` before your `self.presentViewController(popoverContent!, animated: true, completion: nil)` line inside `imageButton` method of `RERUN_SETUP` controller.

Comment: Value of type UIViewController has no member 'delegate'

Comment: Change your this line `let popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectPhotos")` with `let popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectPhotos")
 as! SelectPhotos`

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when I get this error, it has something to do with me having an extra "?" or "!" somewhere. Or that I'm missing one somewhere. Try messing around with those and see if it fixes your bug.